# Scroll to top in a lightbox

Tags: javascript

I have created a customized menu. See [here](http://www.richihotel.com/catering_menu.php). On click of this link I have a shadowbox popping up which has a long list of items. Now I want to have a "back to top" anchor link which takes me back to the top of the menu list.

Comment: What's the link you're talking about ? Can you be more precise (add some code/fiddle) ?

Comment: if you can open the link I have given, there is a link called "create a customised menu" . Now if you click that then there will be a pop up opening which is a shadow box. Inside the shadow box there is a list of food items to pick from. Now its a long list. Hence I want a back to top option at the end of this list.

Comment: You can easily do it in a normal page using javascipt. But I want the feature in a shadow box.

Comment: It's exactly the same procedure but within your iframe. Try something at least.

Comment: I have tried. Its not working. And yes a shadow box is not same as an iframe.  Can you share me an example?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pure Javascript but I could do it with the jQuery framework if you want.

Comment: please share one in jquery then. a jsfiddle will do..thanks in advance.

Comment: You should omit the `height:100%` on your body of the iframe to get rid of the nasty second scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I've set your lightbox with the `#box` id.

**Html**

```
<div id="box">
...
<!-- long content there -->
<a href="#" id="toTop">To Top</a>
</div>
```

**CSS** (setting the width of elements)

```
#box {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#box #toTop {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:150px;
    top:10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#box').bind('scroll', function(e) {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
        $('#toTop').css({'top' : $(this).scrollTop() + 100});
   } else {
        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#toTop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //$('#box').scrollTop(0); //just go to top
    $('#box').animate({scrollTop : 0},'slow'); //animate
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/yrrt9/)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy with:

```
document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Now put a button on the page and call that on click. Oh, and omit the `height:100%` on your body of the iframe, this way you get rid of the second scrollbar.

You can try this out by just pasting the line above and executing it in the console of your browser with your webpage.